# This statement should change the catagory_name column to “Woodwinds”, and it should use the category_id column to identify the row. I keepgetting 1062

Tags: mysql

Write an INSERT statement that adds this row to the `categories` table:

`category_name: Brass`

Code the INSERT statement so MySQL automatically generates the category_id column.

```
insert into categories 
(category_id, category_name)
values 
(default, 'Brass');
```

Comment: A more complete error message is 1062: Duplicate Entry. Why would there be a duplicate entry?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `category_id` is declared `AUTO_INCREMENT`, you get the generated value by either leaving out the column or specifying the value as `NULL`.

```
INSERT INTO categories (category_name)
VALUES ('Brass')
```

```
insert into categories 
(category_id, category_name)
values 
(NULL, 'Brass');
```